# Weight paint isn't visible

Tags: cycles-render-engine, armature, weight-painting, pose-mode

Going into weight paint mode, the weights aren't visible at all. There's not even the 0 weight blue. They're there and working though because I can pose the character, and I can paint because it changes her pose when I do, but I just can't see it at all. I'm sure it's just a simple button I need to press or something but I can't find the solution by searching so that's why I'm posting it here. You can see in my screenshots that I'm in weight paint mode, but no weights are visible, and she can be posed.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have selected this object and not another? Also, in the Viewport Overlays panel, make sure the Weight Paint Opacity is somewhere above 0?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! That literally solved it, I wasn't aware of that feature though and I'm not sure why it was turned down but I'm glad I know now!  :)

Answer (score 3):

In the *Viewport Overlays* panel, make sure that the *Weight Paint Opacity* is somewhere above 0:

[image]